# Temprory collection returns count as zero

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have one large collection from which I am creating some temporary collection using aggregation . My collection has created but when I try to count number of document it returns me ZERO
To create collection

```
await maincollection.aggregate(([{ $skip: 2 }, { $limit: 5 }, { $out: newcollection }]));
```

To count documents

```
await newcollection.countDocuments()
```

The above query returns 0 but when I run `db.new collection.count()` from terminal it returns me exact count

Comment: is newcollection empty ?

Comment: newcollection has data.

Comment: try this `await newcollection.countDocuments({})`

Comment: Still giving me zero count

Comment: you could use newcollection.aggregate([{$count:'total'}])

Comment: it returns me []